# What does "Security condition not satisfied" response APDU mean?

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, access-control, apdu

I am playing with my NFC card with Android NFC API. I am stuck at this APDU response: **Security condition not satisfied** (SW1=69, SW2=82).

Can anyone explain to me what this response means?

Here is a related issue: [69 82Security condition not satisfied ADPU resposne with android NFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548209/69-82security-condition-not-satisfied-adpu-resposne-with-android-nfc)

Answer (score 2):

The status word `69 82` ("Security status not satisfied") typically means that your current authentication state is insufficient to access a certain resource on the card. E.g. if you get that in response to an UPDATE BINARY command, you might not have permission to change the content of the file. Similarly, if you get that in response to a READ BINARY command, you might not have permission to read binary data (random access) from the file.

Comment: @michale Roland : thank you for the clarifications. BUT how this is working within my java application using  javax.smartcardio with laptop's card reader slot. ?? 
So over NFC I dnt have permission  to read the content but with laptop's card reader i have.??

Comment: @Mr.Vicky That's a separate question (that you posted) and that's far beyond what you asked in this one.